# Python List Comprehension cross sum /total

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I tried to write a listcomprehension, which forms the cross-sum of all numbers between 0 and 1000.

```
[ x for x in range(1001) sum([int(y) for y in str(x)])]
```

I would like to have a list containing:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4 .... 27,1]
```

Comment: Why not start with a simpler for loop, and then go towards a list comprehension

Comment: hmm how do you mean ?

Comment: First write a normal `for` loop that does what you want using `result.append()`. Then see if you can turn it into a one-liner list comprehension.

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand what you're trying to do. Where does `27` come from?

Comment: @Barmar 27 is the sum of the digits in 999, which is the second-to-last number in his sequence.

Comment: I figured it out just before you posted. Thanks.

Comment: If @John Gordon's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. This helps both the person who answered your question and yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nearly had it:

```
[sum(int(y) for y in str(x)) for x in range(1001)]
```